# IOS and Zoom Display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iosdeployment

i have issue with zoomed display. 
on IOS until today  i did not see any changes on my apps when user turn on zoom display .
now i developing an application, use auto layout constraints like always , 
but this is the first time that i saw that when user change setting to zoom display zoomed mode all my app get zoomed and the resolution get messy.
i tried every thing to understand the difference and stil get nothing.
i want to ignore the zoom, that the app act like normal mode,
is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore the scaling... I think adding proper launchscreen file in your target settings may solve your problem.

Comment: i just use a proper launchscreen for all sizes and stil the view scale

Comment: can you explain ?